# An error occurs when I am trying to run a maven project on Jenkins: Non-readable

Tags: maven, jenkins, settings, project

```
Caused by: hudson.maven.MavenEmbedderException: 
1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings 
/Users/ravahanbektemurmekov/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin: 
/Users/ravahanbektemurmekov/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin (Is a directory) 
@ /Users/ravahanbektemurmekov/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin

at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:262)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.buildMavenExecutionRequest(MavenEmbedder.java:159)
at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.<init>(MavenEmbedder.java:121)
... 14 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.settings.building.SettingsBuildingException: 
 1 problem was encountered while building the effective settings
[FATAL] Non-readable settings /*/*/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin: 
/*/*/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin (Is a directory) @ 
/Users/*/Downloads/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin

    at org.apache.maven.settings.building.DefaultSettingsBuilder.build(DefaultSettingsBuilder.java:129)
    at hudson.maven.MavenEmbedder.getSettings(MavenEmbedder.java:260)
    ... 16 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

I could not fix the error and run my maven project properly. Can someone help me with this ?